# Error : signature verification failed

Tags: android, installation

Need help solving problem with my Haier W858 android Mobile phone to install a costum rom. while I attempt several times by several ways like adb side load + from Sd card + intalling CWR mod, but all ways got this error... E:signature verification failed...[image]
below is a screen shoot of the problem

Answer (score 0):

ROM should be signed with the same signature.....previous one and the new one

Comment: thnx for ur prompt response, I dont know what u mean, my phone need to be reset or need anew ROM, because there is many things appear and attempt to install without my choice, I did a hard reset and factory reset but nothig change... could u help more please, I need a massive help ...

Comment: my phone model number Haier w858,  build number:HW-W858-H01-A2-S008